"Undefined Function" in query
I have created a Public Function to calculate the Working Days between 2 different dates. I have following every step of a Youtube Video explaining how to do this. But when I create a field for this function in a query it displays the "Undefined Function" error.
I created the following Public Function Code to calculate the working days between two dates and saved it successfully.
I intend to show the result (the number of working days) on a Report that's based on a Query named "In_Progress_All".
Public Function WorkingDaysFC(LRD_Walid As Date, Status_Date As Date) As Long

    Dim D As Date
    
    WorkingDaysFC = 0
    D = LRD_Walid
    While D <= Status_Date
        If Weekday(D) > 1 And Weekday(D) < 7 Then
            WorkingDaysFC = WorkingDaysFC + 1
        End If
        D = D + 1
    Wend
End Function

Then I open the query in design mode and create a field at the very end of as follows:
WD: WorkingDaysFC([LRD_Walid],[Status_Date])
When I run the query the following error is displayed:
"Undefined Function 'WorkingDaysFC' in expression."
Any idea what is wrong with this process? Or even if there's another easier way to calculate the number of working days between two dates in a Report's Textbox.

It matters where you have this function (in which module). Try to place this function in a module that is not linked to the form.

@ValNik Can you tell me who to do that? I'm a newbie in VBA functions. I just copied the function from the Youtube video and altered only the Field Names.

You may have placed your function in the report module. You need to create a separate module in this application and put the function WorkingDaysFC in this module.

Off topic, i think, sould be WD: WorkingDaysFC([LRD_Walid];[Status_Date]). parameters delimiter in query constructor is ;

Also, DO NOT name your module the same as your Public Function.  Excel will never find the function.

From the VBA Editor menu > Insert > Module. Should also set VBA Editor to automatically include line in header Option Explicit. From the VBA Editor menu > Tools > Options > Editor tab > check "Require Variable Declaration". Will have to manually add to existing modules. This includes object related modules.

If code is behind report, could call function from textbox instead of within query. If you want this function to be available by other parts of db, put it in a general module.

Your function does not account for Holidays. This would require a table of Holidays and incorporating into procedure. This is a common topic and many examples available. Do web search.
